# highlight on the cell which is being searched over a column

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

This is I am asking from my curiosity, that I have a Loop which is rolling over a column to match ID,Now after some iterations the script getting closed with a error message: "Match not found"

```
 ParentMatchRowNum=objExcel1.Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ParentID, ob3.Columns(1), 0)
```

So i am looking for a any kind of highlight with color,with its current ID search,just to point out the ID which is not being found by the script. Highlight will needs to be on the current ID which just has passed the search.

**ERROR**

[image: Error]

Thanks

Comment: So you want to highlight the cell of `parentid` within ob3.Columns(1) if it's found in that column? If the answer is yes, that's so illogical.... :$ coz that means you have to highlight the entire column...why don't you track the parentID into a `dictionary` when it's not found in the column?

Comment: @bonCodigo I don't know why it is happened. because the ID the match function was searching is present in that column, i just found through the debug. still why the match throwing error? is there any limitation to the match function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `Application.Match` instead of `Application.WorksheetFunction.Match`.

```
If not IsError(objExcel1.Application.Match(ParentID, ob3.Columns(1), 0)) Then    
   ParentMatchRowNum = objExcel1.Application.Match(ParentID, ob3.Columns(1), 0)
Else
   '-- do something
End if
```

Here is a little info that a MVP has shared: 
**Difference between Application.Match() vs Application.WorkSheetFunction.Match()**

The difference lies in its error handling. In XL97, there was a problem with the `WorksheetFunction` form of Match that did not manifest with `Application.Match`. *Myrna Larson* reports that she has experienced that problem in later versions. For that reason, it is generally agrreed to be
safe rather than sorry and use `Application.Match`.

:-[Reference](http://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/358571-application-match.html).

One other thing is, just be aware you shouldn't search for a String when there are only integers in the column or mix data types. Keep things consistent. So for e.g. look for `integers within integers` or `Strings within Strings`.. Which means you should probably convert all of your `alphanumeric` ID references to `CStr(ID)`. (Variants are interpreted at runtime, so it doesn't solve the issue.)

Comment: You are my **GOD** honestly speaking! You are my `Life Saver` :-) but really once my script will be over means all the requirement will be converted to `CODE` I will then start with error handling body in my script!

Comment: I am getting error that`IsError` variable is not defined from that part.please help!!

Comment: please see the description,I just attached!